# Slick slider animate back to first slide

Tags: slick.js

I am trying to make a Slick slider jump back to the first slide after the last slide. The closest answer to this topic I have found is this:

[Slick slider goto first slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986346/slick-slider-goto-first-slide)

But unfortunately it uses the fade animation so it does not have the effect I'm after. What I want is that the slideshow will play until the end and then scroll back to the beginning after the last slide is shown.

There are only three slides in my use case, and I can easily fire a message in the console when the last one is reached, but the slickslider method slickGoTo doesn't work.

```js
(function($) {
  var slider = $('.sightbox__slideshow');
     
     slider.slick({
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
        infinite: true,
      });

      function jumpBack() {
        slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);
      }

      slider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        console.log(currentSlide);
        if (currentSlide === 2 ) {
          console.log('last slide');
          jumpBack();
        }
      });
      
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.sightbox__slideshow {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.sightbox__slide--1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
.sightbox__slide--2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.sightbox__slide--3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="sightbox__slideshow">
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--1" id="sightbox__slide--1">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">1. first</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--2" id="sightbox__slide--2">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">2. second</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--3" id="sightbox__slide--3">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">3. third</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
```

Comment: Strange, but seems like we can't trigger an action on the slick slider with a built-in event (beforeChange) or on click of an element of the slider (slick-prev). Whereas it can be triggered on click of another element. Check this fiddle - https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/OvNVpy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may change the trigger event to `afterChange` and resort to `setTimeout` function to stay on the last slide for a while (3 seconds approx).

The slick-slider preventing a custom action on its events can also be overridden using the `setTimeout` function.

```
function jumpBack() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    slider.slick("slickGoTo", 0);
  },3000);
}
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/BrKodJ)

Hope this helps.